# Java Proxy-Authorization in the aws request header for uploading to S3 using a proxy server

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to aws s3 and there is a proxy server in between and the proxy servers uses a token.
I am requested to send the credentials on header as “Proxy-Authorization”. Here is the code I am using.

```
com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
config.addHeader(“Proxy-Authorization”, “Basic $$$$$$$$$“); 
config.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS); 
config.setProxyHost(proxyHost);
config.setProxyPort(proxyPort);

BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secret);

AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withClientConfiguration(config)
    .withCredentials(new 
 AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
 
s3Client.putObject(name,key,file)
```

I am getting HTTP 403.Forbidden error, when we try to upload to s3 (using s3Client putObject )

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null;

I tried the same using a curl command with  -H "Proxy-Authorization:Basic $$$$" and it worked fine. Appreciate any help on how can I pass the header in the request from a java code.